# Looking for an identity for characteristic polynomial of a matrix to the power of n

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory, determinant

Is there any identity to help finding the characteristic polynomial of a power of a matrix in terms of its own characteristic polynomial?

Let $A\in \mathbb{Z}^{m\times m}$, we have $$p(t)=\text{det}(A-t I)$$
If we define $$q(t)=\text{det}(A^n-t I)\,\,,n\in\mathbb{N}$$
Is there any identity relating $p(t)$ to $q(t)$?

If there is no general relation between $p(t)$ and $q(t)$, is there any relation to compute $q(1)$ from $p(1)$?

Comment: So I suppose $p(t) = q(t^n)$.

Comment: I do! It follows from first principles and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @EliRose This doesn't hold. Note that already the degree of $p$ is wrong.

Comment: @Dominik: Yep, you're right. My mistake and I apologize. Disregard.

Comment: @Dominik: I'm curious, though -- why does the following proof not work? Start with $A\mathbf{x} = \lambda \mathbf{x}$ where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Multiply by $A$ on both sides $n$ times, using $A\mathbf{x} = \lambda \mathbf{x}$ to conclude $A^n \mathbf{x} = \lambda^n \mathbf{x}$. Then follow the same process as usual (as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial), under "Motivation") to get $\det(A^n - t^n I) = 0$.

Comment: @EliRose You only get $\det(A^n - \lambda^nI) = 0$. This doesn't tell you much about the characteristic polynomial. To see some examples consider $A = I_2$, $B = -I_2$ and $C = \operatorname{diag}(1, -1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now if $A$ is any martix, then there is an invertable matrix $G$, such that $GAG^{-1}$ is upper-triangular. Since we have $det(GAG^{-1})=det(A)$, $det(GAG^{-1}-\lambda I)=det(G(A-\lambda I)G^{-1})=det(A-\lambda I)$, and $GA^nG^{-1}=(GAG^{-1})^n$, we may assume that $A$ is upper triangular. Now note that if $A$ is upper-triangular, write $A=D+N$ for $D$ the diagonal and $N$ a strictly upper-triangular matrix. Then we have that $A^n=(D+N)^n=\sum_i D^iN^{n-i}\binom{n}{i}=D^n+N'$, where $N'$ is strictly upper triangular. We have that $p_{A^n}(\lambda)=det(A^n-\lambda I)=det(D^n-\lambda I)$ since the strictly upper triangular part doesn't affect the determinant. We also have $p_A(\lambda)=det(D-\lambda I)$. We thus can see, by the formula for the determinant of a diagonal matrix, that if $p_A(\lambda)=\prod_i (\lambda-y_i)$ then $p_A(\lambda)=\prod_i (\lambda-y_i^n)$.

Comment: In the 4th line it seems that $p_{A^n}(\lambda)$ is not a polynomial of the same degree as $p_A(\lambda)$, but they should have same degrees.

Comment: @SMA.D Yes! Thanks for catching that! Luckly I ignored that mistake, so the conclusion still stands.

Comment: Is it possible to find same result for this matrix? $$A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a_1  & \ldots & a_{m-1}& a_m\\
1 & \ldots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots  & \ddots & \vdots &\vdots\\
0 &  \ldots &1 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: @SMA.D Yeap! It holds for all matrices, I added a bit at the beginning that explains that, since I have a bad habit of figuring of forgotting my beginning steps once I get to the end. So in particular, it does hold for $A$. But, you have to factor the corresponding polynomial, since there is no simple relation between the coefficents of  $\prod_i (x-y_i)$ and $\prod_i (x-y_i^n)$.

Comment: How can I compute $G$ for my matrix?

Comment: In general, I think it hard to give an exact form, atleast in a decently computable form, since it would amount to giving an algorithm to factor the polynomials $p_A(\lambda)$, and this is hard. That said, I might be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for answering. In that case are you sure that $G$ always exists (It seems that existence of $G$ is enough for your proof)?

Comment: Yeap! Jordon normal form will suffice for example!

Comment: Also note that it suffices to work over $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$ since this doesn't affect the characteristic polynomials, since indeed, these often done exist over $\mathbb{Z}$!

Answer (score 2):

If $$A=\pmatrix{r&0\cr0&r/(r-1)\cr}$$ then $p(1)=1$ but (using $n=2$) $q(1)=(2r^2+r-1)/(r-1)$ if I've done my arithmetic correctly. This shows there is no hope of computing $q(1)$ if all you know is $p(1)$.